# How to localize Identity in Blazor?

Tags: c#, internationalization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I read [this helpful article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/localization-in-blazor-server/) about general localization of Blazor pages, however, Identity is not quite the same. It uses ASP.NET Core MVC, not Blazor. I made my example page localized, but scaffolded register page does't see my translation.

My `ConfigureServices` method fragment:

```cs
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
var supportedCultures = new[] {
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("pl"),
};
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("pl");
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

My `Configure` method fragment:

```cs
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

I placed my `Register.pl.resx` file in `Resources\Identity\Account` folder.
My `resx` file fragment:

```xml
<data name="Password" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Hasło</value>
</data>
```

I changed my `Register.cshtml` file like this:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<RegisterModel> L

...

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password">@L["Password"]</label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

And... No joy. Doesn't work. I changed the first language in browser to Polish. Didn't help.
I suspect several things. Like the localizer service takes a type argument. Maybe I should use something else instead of the model type? Then, maybe `.resx` file folder / name should be different? Or maybe it should be done completely different?

BTW, I also need full app localisation, with ability to change language with a link like in site path, exactly like it's made on Microsoft pages. I found some examples for MVC, but none in Blazor, and Blazor with Identity is like Blazor with MVC. How to make localization / internationalization right and by the book in Blazor server-side application?

Comment: Could it be a typo in 'Resouorces', in this line `services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resouorces");`?

Comment: @JoseLuis Thanks, there was a typo, I fixed it, but still doesn't work. I tried several naming conventions like Resources/Identity/Account/Register.resx, Resources/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.resx and both with PageModel.resx, still nothing. It would work for a normal Blazor page, but not for Identity MVC page.

Comment: I know nothing about Blazor.  In an net core mvc app, I have the *.resx files in the folder `\Resources\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\` and `\Resources\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @JoseLuis Works! However, the only way to set the language is now through browser's language list. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Hi.  In this links you have more information:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request.  Hope this helps :-)